# how do you use sass in create-react-app with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, create-react-app

I created a fresh project using create-react-app and typescript and added a sass file in my project (in create-react-app docs it says that it supports sass file out of the box) but I'm getting this error for my sass file:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/homepage.style.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/homepage.style.sass)
SassError: Invalid CSS after ".homepage {": expected "}", was "{"
        on line 1 of /home/taghi/wt-projects/react-ecommerce/src/homepage.style.sass
>> .homepage { {

   -----------^
```

and here is my Sass file content:

```
.homepage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px;
}

.directory-menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu-item {
  min-width: 30%;
  height: 240px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 7.5px 15px;

  &:first-child {
    margin-right: 7.5px;
  }

  &:last-child {
    margin-left: 7.5px;
  }

  .content {
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;

    .title {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #4a4a4a;
    }

    .subtitle {
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SASS syntax is indent based, it doesn't use braces.... so just change your file to a .scss file

Comment: good call, That was the problem and it's working now. Thanks @TomFinney

Answer (score 1):

Sass does not need curly brackets and semicolons. So it should look like this,

`.homepage 
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  padding: 20px 80px`

You can just remove the curly brackets and semicolons in the current CSS code or [json Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/css-to-sass) to convert CSS to SASS.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need "{}"，only use indentation

```
.homepage 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px;
```